# Android - Request code in onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

can I access the requestCode an activity received in its onCreate() method?

I'd need it to understand if it is a "new" or "modify" operation.

Comment: I suspect you want to read requestCode inside the Activity that was started using `startActivityForResult()`. Pass your request code as an extra in your Intent as well before calling `startActivityForResult()` and then read it in `onCreate()` using `getIntent().getExtras();`. There is no other way.

Comment: I suspected. But, honestly, this is stupid. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: The request code is only for your own purpose, in the calling Activity. That way you know what Activity finished in the onActivityResult method.

Comment: Request code is meant for calling Activity, you should not use it. Instead you should pass something more intuitive of your own like Uri etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you create an activity **A** :

The activity lifecycle goes like this : `A.onCreate() -> A.onStart() -> A.onResume()`

Then you call activity **B** from activity **A**. You want activity **B** to send you back a result.

The activity lifecycle goes like this : `A.onPause -> B.onCreate ->B.onStart()-> B.onResume()->A.onStop()`

Once **B** has done its job, it will send a result and destroyed itself : `B.onDestroy()->A.onResume()-> A.onActivityResultBack()`

My whole point is that the activity **A** does not go back to `onCreate` ! So unless you have an attribute requestCode in your *activityA.java* file, you can not access it in its `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

To see if it's a "new" or "modified" activity, you should override the onActivityResult method in the activity. If the onActivityResult is getting called, that means the activity is "modified".

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html for how to use the onActivityResult.