# onActivityResult of an Activity not called after startActivityForResult of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two activities **ActivityOne** and **ActivityTwo** each one contains one **Fragment**

i did `startActivityForResult(mIntent, Request_code)` from the fragment of the first activity (**ActivityOne**) for calling the second activity (**ActivityTwo**), the problem is `onActivityResult` of the second activity has not being called?

Comment: `onActivityResult` will be called in the first activity when the second activity has been completed, and not in the second activity itself.

Comment: onActivityResult of the second activity will be called if you start an activity (with startActivityForResult()) from the second activity

Comment: yes you're right but how i can call the onActivityResult of the second activity because this is the problem?

Comment: I assume you are trying to pass something (e.g. data, object, etc) from ActivityOne to ActivityTwo? Maybe you can briefly explain what you're trying to achieve with ActivityOne & ActivityTwo.

Comment: yes but i want to work with requestCode and from this request code i can distinct which action i do and which data i receive because i have many action!

Comment: Pass the request code using `public Intent putExtra (String name, int[] value)` in ActivityOne & use `public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)` in ActivityTwo? That's one way that I can think of.

Comment: Here, in this link, it is mentioned that this is the only way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219926/android-request-code-in-oncreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `onActivityResult` will only be called in the activity (e.g. **ActivityOne**) that started some other activity (e.g. **ActivityTwo**) for a result, using `startActivityForResult(...)`;

You can read up on this in the developer guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

If, by any chance, you are trying to pass something from **ActivityOne** to **ActivityTwo**,
you can use [putExtra(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20double[])) in **ActivityOne** & use [getExtra(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)) in **ActivityTwo**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `onActivityResult` method of the fragment of first activity inside `onActivityResult` method of first Activity. In other words you have to delegate `onActivityResult` method form activity to fragment. `onActivityResult` of your second activity will be called only if you call `startActivityResult` from within your second activity.

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult of your second activity will be called if u call startActivityResult from within your second activity.In your case the onActivityResult of the first activity will be called

Answer (score 0):

ActivityOne onActivityResult will call onCreate of ActivityTwo.

In ActivityTwo, when you call setResult(requestNo,returnIntent), this will call the onActivityResult of ActivityOne.